# HttpServer vs. Servlet - which approach to take to show an updating BufferedImage

Tags: java, servlets, bufferedimage, httpserver

I have a Java application, and would like to serve out a BufferedImage (that is updated a few times a second) to a web client.

I've started by looking at HttpServer (part of JDK 6).  I've implemented an HttpHandler, and on the handle(HttpExchange exchange) call I grab the latest BufferedImage and send it out using the exchange reference.

I can use my web browser to view the image sent via exchange, and as I refresh the browser I can observe the image updating (since my application is updating the BufferedImage).

For the next step, I would like to continuously update the image in the browser (without needing to manually refresh the web page).  It seems that HttpServer with an associated HttpHandler is not really set up to do this (just a one time request/response).  I've started to read about Servlets and am looking into using Jetty.

I'd like to know if I'm on the right track with looking into Servlets, or is there a way to "drive" BufferedImage updates to a web client that has connected to my HttpServer?

Thanks in advance.

Code snippet blow for my handle method:

```
public void handle(HttpExchange exch) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = fImageProvider.getLatestImage();
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream(SIZE);
    ImageIO.write(image, IMAGE_CODEC, output);
    byte[] byteArray = output.toByteArray();

    exch.sendResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, byteArray.length);
    exch.getResponseBody().write(byteArray);
    exch.close
}
```

Comment: You can use websockets to open a two-way comms channel between server and browser, but maybe the answer is a low-tech META refresh tag in the HTML page. That will get the browser to do the refresh automatically.

Comment: From reading about the meta tag, I don't think it will provide the refresh rate I need (2-5Hz).  I read up a little about websockets.  It seems Jetty also provides this.  I'm going to start by learning a bit more about servlets and see where it leads.  Thanks for the response Paul.

Comment: Why don't you just stream it as video?

Comment: This is a very new technology area to me Balus.  Could you point me to where to get started in learning how to stream the updating bufferedimage as a video?